# SQL query where one column's value does not contain another column's value

Tags: sql, contains, not-exists

I am looking for data in a table where a value in one column does not contain data from another column(s).

The key column I'm looking at is Item Number. I want to look for where this value does not have a record with a specific City or State.

So for example, I'm looking for all Item Numbers that do not have New York, NY as the City and State. I don't want all of the other values returned like Chicago, IL or Detroit, MI for that specific Item Number, I just want to know which Item Number records do not have New York, NY as one of the locations.

Let's say Item Number 43879 has 6 records with different locations and one of them is New York, NY. I wouldn't want this Item Number in my results.
Let's say Item Number 89043 has 4 records and none of these records has New York, NY as a location. I would like this Item Number to appear in my results.

Comment: What RDBMS? What are the relevant table names and column names, and what is your query/results so far and how is it failing you?

Comment: a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `not exists`.  Assuming you have two tables, this would look something like:

```
select i.*
from items i
where not exists (select 1
                  from itemlocations il
                  where il.item_number = i.item_number and
                        il.state = 'NY' and il.city = 'New York'
                 );
```